# JAXB class creation through xsd and getting result of unmarshalling of xml in object of the class

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

Through Jaxb, created a class using (xjc -d C:\temp -p  *proj path* *xsd *)(in cmd)from the xsd file,while using the same class object to read the result of unmarshalling of the xml file whose xsd we used.

> Error: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to
>   TypeConversionSteps.Conversion.ESPARKType.
>
> conversion cmd command : xjc -d C:\temp -p  MarshalAnd
>   C:\Users\shuklqq\Documents\MarshalAndUnmarshal\OCLEntry.xsd

Unmarshalling Code

```
public void unmarshal() throws JAXBException , IOException{
        try{

            ESPARKType test1 = new ESPARKType();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ESPARKType.class.getPackage().getName());
            System.out.println (context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\shuklqq\\Documents\\Conversion\\target\\OCL.xml")));
            test1 = (ESPARKType)context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\shuklqq\\Documents\\Conversion\\target\\OCL.xml"));
            System.out.println(test1);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error message:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@4459eb14 ERROR javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>   cannot be cast to TypeConversionSteps.Conversion.ESPARKType
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be
>   cast to TypeConversionSteps.Conversion.ESPARKType     at
>   TypeConversionSteps.Conversion.ApplicationUnmarshalling.unmarshal(ApplicationUnmarshalling.java:18)
>     at
>   TypeConversionSteps.Conversion.ConversionApplication.main(ConversionApplication.java:15)